# Get Bluetooth MAC Address via adb

Tags: android, bluetooth, adb, mac-address

Please help me to retrieve the *Bluetooth MAC Address* of my Galaxy S3 phone connected via USB port. My device is rooted.

Comment: Have you tried running `ifconfig -a` from the device's command line (`adb shell`) ?

Comment: i have connect my device and run "adb devices" and it's present.
Now i want retrieve the bluetooth mac address....

Comment: did you try any of the tricks mentioned here .. http://alexandre.alapetite.fr/doc-alex/mobile-bluetooth-mac/index.en.php or http://alexandre.alapetite.fr/doc-alex/mobile-bluetooth-mac-qrcode/? these seem agnostic to whether the phone is rooted or not

Comment: I posted a possible answer to your question please check it out. @Antonio

Answer (score 30):

Running `netcfg` will show you all interfaces on the system along with their MAC addresses.

Comment: It works. The Bluetooth MAC address shows up as pan0.

Comment: My Moto G 2015 doesn't have `netcfg` command. Running AICP ROM.

Answer (score 23):

`adb shell cat /sys/class/net/wlan0/address`

Comment: The best, no-nonsense, answer. `ifconfig` doesn't list the MAC address, there's no `netcfg` on my Moto G 2015.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer

Comment: Need root permission on my android.

Comment: This provides me with the Wifi mac address but not the BT one.....

Answer (score 15):

What I usually do to get the **mac address** of the WiFi interface of an Android device (*that is connected to my PC through a USB port*) is following these easy steps:

#### 1. Find the device name using:

```sh
adb devices
```

Results usually looks like:

> ```sh
> List of devices attached 
> 4e7354af  device
> 1f97033e  device
> ```

In this case we have two devices connected `4e7354af` and `1f97033e`. Let's work on the first one: `4e7354af`

#### 2. Get the **mac address** for the first device:

```sh
adb -s 4e7354af shell "ip addr show wlan0  | grep 'link/ether '| cut -d' ' -f6"
```

The result will be looks like:

> ```sh
> 8e:5a:e7:c2:01:9b
> ```

In previous line, we used the `-s` option of the `adb` command to specify the serial number. Then we call the `shell` command to indicate that we will run a **Linux** command. Finally, we run the command: `ip addr show wlan0 | grep 'link/ether '| cut -d' ' -f6` this command can also be used in Linux if its interface has the same name as `wlan0`.

I generally use this approach because I have many devices connected to my testing environment. Good luck guys.

**Note:** If you run commands like `cat /sys/class/net/wlan0/address` you will get an error like `cat: /sys/class/net/wlan0/address: Permission denied` due to the security policies of Android.

Comment: This is the best answer (ip addr show wlan0) when "ifconfig" doesn't display a mac address, regardless of command line arguments, "netcfg" isn't installed, which is common and when adb lacks sufficient privileges to read "/sys/class/net/wlan0/address" because the device isn't rooted.

Many thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Isn't bluetooth MAC address available on every Android phone in Settings?

Currently I have 2 devices near:

On Samsung Galaxy S2 - Settings > About Phone > Status

On HTC Desire - Settings > About Phone > Hardware Information

(Bluetooth must be turned on)